# Float pointer as void and then referencing it to float again

Tags: c, pointers

I have an array of floats and I get their value through a function which is receiving a void pointer and writes the data on the pointer. (my idea is to not only use it for 
floats)

```
float fArray[3];

GetValue( fArray ); //this function makes the filling

printf( "IN:%f\n", fArray[0] );
printf( "IN:%f\n", fArray[1] );
printf( "IN:%f\n", fArray[2] );

fArray[0] = *( (float *) fArray );
fArray[1] = *( (float *) fArray + 4 );
fArray[2] = *( (float *) fArray + 8 );

printf( "DEREF:%f\n", fArray[0] );
printf( "DEREF:%f\n", fArray[1] );
printf( "DEREF:%f\n", fArray[2] );
```

GetValue:

```
void GetValue(void * array ){
    for ( BYTE i = 0; i <  MAX_POINTS; i++ ) {
        float f = dataRegisters[i].fData;
        memcpy( array + sizeof(float)*i, &f, sizeof(float) );
    }
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
IN:677.000000
IN:0.000000
IN:0.000000
DEREF:677.000000
DEREF:23.600000
DEREF:58.299999
```

Why is this happening? Is it a good idea to use a void pointer? Is there a cleaner way to dereference?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The argument is `array`, but the code uses `fArray`?

Comment: what does D(...) mean? is it some c++ thing?

Comment: If `fArray` is a `float*`, then `fArray + 4` is definitely not what you wanted to do. Since you are missing a [mcve], it's rather hard to help you.

Comment: Yup, there's some important stuff missing from this code snippet.

Comment: I should point out that adding a number to a pointer type actually adds that number multiplied by the sizeof the type its pointing to

Comment: What exactly are the assignments supposed to be accomplishing?  It seems that all they're doing is moving things around in the array.

Comment: `fArray + 4` and `fArray + 8` are accessing the array beyond its bounds, invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: But more generally, this doesn't seem like a good time to use void pointers anyway. Why not make your function `void GetValue(float* array)`, then you can simply replace the body of your loop with `array[i] = dataRegisters[i].fData;`

Comment: I am concerned about your statement “my idea is to not only use it for floats.” There are rules in the C standard about the use of pointers, and you should follow them. There are various nifty manipulations you can do with pointers, but you need to know what the rules are if you want your code to be reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oups, C automatically processes pointer arithmetics according to the pointed type. So whatever type `p` points at, the following equality is true *per definition*:

```
p[i] == *(p + i)
```

Comment: That was it. Actually, the function GetValue( fArray ) which was not specified in the question was not considering this and it was adding i * sizeof(float).

Answer (score 0):

try adding brackets around `fArray + 4` and `fArray + 8`

```
void GetValue( void * fArray ) {


D( printf( "IN:%f\n", fArray[0] ) );
D( printf( "IN:%f\n", fArray[1] ) );
D( printf( "IN:%f\n", fArray[2] ) );

fArray[0] = *( (float *) fArray );
fArray[1] = *( (float *) (fArray + 4) );
fArray[2] = *( (float *) (fArray + 8) );

D( printf( "DEREF:%f\n", fArray[0] ) );
D( printf( "DEREF:%f\n", fArray[1] ) );
D( printf( "DEREF:%f\n", fArray[2] ) );
```

or do change it to `fArray + 1` and `fArray + 2` (the prefered method)

```
void GetValue( void * fArray ) {


D( printf( "IN:%f\n", fArray[0] ) );
D( printf( "IN:%f\n", fArray[1] ) );
D( printf( "IN:%f\n", fArray[2] ) );

fArray[0] = *( (float *) fArray );
fArray[1] = *( (float *) fArray + 1 );
fArray[2] = *( (float *) fArray + 2 );

D( printf( "DEREF:%f\n", fArray[0] ) );
D( printf( "DEREF:%f\n", fArray[1] ) );
D( printf( "DEREF:%f\n", fArray[2] ) );
```

the issue you are having is you are typecasting the pointer to a `(float *)` so the compiler thinks that when you want to add `+4` to it, you want to increment the pointer by `4 * sizeof((float))`

Comment: How is the `array` parameter of `GetValue` used in these code fragments?

Comment: oh my bad question has been updated

Comment: Standard C does not define the behavior of adding to a `void *`. GCC allows it as an extension, but this seems pointless as there is a standard-conforming way to do it that should be recommended: Convert to a pointer to a character type and add. (And then convert to `float *` if desired.)

Answer (score 0):

Answering the new version!

I'm guessing in

```
fArray[0] = *( (float *) fArray );
fArray[1] = *( (float *) fArray + 4 );
fArray[2] = *( (float *) fArray + 8 );
```

you expect `fArray + 4` to point to `fArray[1]` assuming `sizeof(float) == 4`.
But `(float *) fArray + 4` is equivalent to `&fArray[4]`, or memory wise

```
fArray + 4*sizeof(float)
```

Which points to an unknown area (fArray[4] is not defined).

This is undefined behavior, and you might get any value from the last prints, even good ones with a bit of luck, or a segfault etc...

(same reasoning for `*( (float *) fArray + 8 )` which is `fArray[8]`, also undefined)

Answer (score 0):

The "dereferencing" you're doing is nothing of the sort.  You're just moving elements around in the array.

Let's take a closer look:

```
fArray[0] = *( (float *) fArray );
fArray[1] = *( (float *) fArray + 4 );
fArray[2] = *( (float *) fArray + 8 );
```

Since `fArray` is of type `float[3]`, it decays to type `float *` in most expressions, so the cast is unnecessary.  So the above is the same as:

```
fArray[0] = *( fArray );
fArray[1] = *( fArray + 4 );
fArray[2] = *( fArray + 8 );
```

Also, because of the rules of pointer arithmetic, `a[i]` is the same as `*(a + i)`.  So the above is the same as:

```
fArray[0] = fArray[0];
fArray[1] = fArray[4];
fArray[2] = fArray[8];
```

Given that `fArray` has size 3, it should be apparent what the problem is now.  Get rid of these three lines entirely.  They don't do anything useful.

Your `GetValue` function is already doing the proper pointer arithmetic to load values into the array.  You don't need to do any post-processing.